# How to get (random) number from Gaussian Mixture model(GMM)?

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian, gmm, gaussian-mixture-model

I want to get a list of random numbers from GMM.

I've plotted a distribution like this.[image]
And I was wondering whether there is some way to get the value from the distribution curve, such as getting number 0.94, 0.96, 0.95.... How to get it?

I am not sure whether the belowing is useful for u or not. I got the code from [Minimal reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187037/how-can-i-do-a-histogram-with-1d-gaussian-mixture-with-sklearn)

```py
from matplotlib import rc
from sklearn import mixture
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import scipy.stats as stats

# x = open("prueba.dat").read().splitlines()

# create the data
x = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(5, 5, 1000),np.random.normal(10, 2, 1000)))

f = np.ravel(x).astype(np.float)
f=f.reshape(-1,1)
g = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=3,covariance_type='full')
g.fit(f)
weights = g.weights_
means = g.means_
covars = g.covariances_

plt.hist(f, bins=100, histtype='bar', density=True, ec='red', alpha=0.5)

# f_axis = f.copy().ravel()
# f_axis.sort()
# plt.plot(f_axis,weights[0]*stats.norm.pdf(f_axis,means[0],np.sqrt(covars[0])).ravel(), c='red')

plt.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.sample) you can simply do `g.sample(n_samples=64)` on the fitted model to generate 64 samples